# Aparently valid regex doesn't work in php ((\\\\|\\\|)|[^\\\|])*?

Tags: php, regex

I was writing very complex regex and tested it using [Rubular editor](http://www.rubular.com/) and after few hours I realize that it doesn't work in PHP.

This is just tiny part of longer regex pattern:

```
((\\\\|\\\|)|[^\\\|])*?
```

I have to mach string under following conditions.

1. String may contain `|` character only escaped as `\|`.
2. String may contain `\` character only escaped as `\\`.
3. String may be empty.

This means that strings like

```
test
test\\
test\|
t\\e\|s\|\|t\\\\\\\\\\
```

are **CORRECT**, and strings like

```
test\
test|\
\
|
test\\\\|
```

are **NOT CORRECT**

Also, Rubular accepts `[^\\\|]` and `[^\|\\]` (same). PHP doesn't work with `[^\|\\]`. Why?

Is here something I don't see because I think that both characters have been escaped correctly but PHP doesn't agree with me.

[See this example in Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/JHOrd84XCg)

I'm still new in this regex thing, so don't blame my stupidity.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a raw string. Does passing  `var_export($yourRegexString, true);` do the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double escape the \ when quoting in PHP.

```
regex = "/((\\\\\\\\|\\\\\\|)|[^\\\\\\|])*?/";
```

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, show us the code you are using so that we can help. You probably want to anchor the expression with `^` and `\z` or `$`.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Haven't escaped some slashes in testing string and seems it works fine now. I'm going to test it with complete pattern to see if that caused problems? Full pattern looks like this `'/(\[(([a-z][a-z0-9]*~)|(~[a-z][a-z0-9]*(\|([a-z][a-z0-9]*(=(((\\\\\\\\|\\\\\\|)|[^\\\\\\|])*?)?)?)?)*~?))])/i'`, but other parts are already tested and this one was problematic. However, your answer is correct and that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.